# Prove that there are $\frac{(n - 1)!}{2}$ distinct tours for a Euclidean traveling salesman problem

Tags: graph-theory

I understand that there are $\frac{(n - 1)!}{2}$ distinct tours for any TSP. However, is there some way to prove this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n=3$ it is clear that there is only $\frac{(3-1)!}2=1$ distinct tour. Assume now that there are $\frac{(n-1)!}2$ distinct tours on $n$ vertices. Each tour on $n+1$ vertices corresponds uniquely to the graph obtained from a tour on $n$ vertices by subdivision of an edge. There are necessarily $n$ edges in a tour on $n$ vertices, and hence there are $n\cdot\frac{(n-1)!}2 = \frac{n!}2 $ distinct tours on $n+1$ vertices.